# ASP.NET IIS Failed Request Tracing event AspNetHttpHandlerEnter

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am troubleshooting a problem with an *ASP.NET ASMX web service* (legacy code) in which some requests are taking a long time to complete (more than 10 seconds).

I added logging to the application and the delay seems to be happening between the event that causes `Global.Application_AcquireRequestState()` to fire, and the first line in my application code which logs entry.

I enabled Failed Request Tracing and the trace for requests over 10 seconds stop at the event `AspNetHttpHandlerEnter`.  My understanding is that the trace ends when the specified time limit is up, so the request was somewhere in/after/near the last event.

What is this event?  Where does it indicate I should look for the problem?

Thanks.